# what is wrong with this loop?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result  = mysql_query($query);
$filter = array(); 
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
   for ( $i = 0; $i<20; $i++)
   {  
      $filter[] = $r["name"][$i]; 
   }
   $name = implode(",", $filter); 
}
```

Above is a portion of main code. I want to restrict loop to run only 20 times. if above 20 it should omit...but this gives me some odd result...I know some where I made a mistake but where?

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_array` only fetches a single row of data from the query results. It looks like you're trying to fetch only a single field from the results, so you'd want something like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $i++
   if ($i >= 20) {
      break;
   }
   $filter[] = $row['name'];

}
$name = implode(",", $filter);
```

But this is very inefficient. Why not have MySQL do the row-limiting itself?

```
SELECT your,fields,here
FROM yourtable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 20
```

and then you only get 20 rows to start with, without forcing mysql to fetch all however-many-there-are-beyond-20.

Comment: OH..so simple you are right..I forgot the LIMIT option..well thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You are not advancing to the next row

```
$result  = mysql_query($query);
$filter = array(); 
$i = 0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 

    $filter[] = $r["name"][$i]; }
    $name = implode(",", $filter); 
    if(++$i == 20)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```